# Javascript API for Evernote?

Tags: javascript, evernote

The [top search result](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/22476-api-for-javascript/) doesn't give me anything. Any existing one?

Answer (score 3):

There is no javascript api to download directly.

However you can download the [thrift files](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-thrift), you should be able to generate a javascript api by running these through [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Evernote API in Node JS. You can use [evernode](https://github.com/cloudsnap/evernode).

Also, you can checkout [my project](https://github.com/berryboy/everest-js) for code example.

Answer (score 2):

Evernote has released [a Javascript SDK here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js)

Answer (score 0):

They don't seem to support JS API .

See http://dev.evernote.com/documentation

```
Supported languages: Objective-C, Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, Perl, C#, C++, ActionScript, JavaME
You make web service calls directly
Provides complete access to the Evernote service
API only - no user interfaces
Cloud API documentation »
```

Answer (score 0):

Kandasoftware has put out a JavaScript API wrapper at https://github.com/kandasoftware/evernote-sdk-javascript under an MIT license.

I haven't used it yet, so I can't comment on its quality. But they are using it in their product, so it should be workable.

See http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/22476-api-for-javascript/ for the link that led me to the repository.